# Enumerating with Prepositions: ''To''

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, sentence, syntactic-analysis

I have a question about the use of prepositions when enumerating things or talking about multiple actions. For the sake of simplicity, I'm only going to use "to". For example, in the phrase:

> "You have until X date **to** register and be eligible for the draw. Grab this chance **to** participate and have a chance of winning a car"

Is the sentence correct as it is? Or would it be necessary to repeat the "to" after listing the consequence of the first action? As in:

> "You have until X date **to** register and **to** be eligible for the draw. Grab this chance **to** participate and **to** have a chance of winning a car."

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

When two or more infinitives/infinitive clauses are connected by

> *and, or, except, but, than, as well as*

the infinitive marker *to* is [almost always omitted](http://www.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/learningenglish/youmeus/learnit/learnitv226.shtml) after the first one:

> My mother asked me to feed the fish and <del>to</del> walk the dog before she came home.
>
> The cookies are fresh from the oven. Would you like to have one now or <del>to</del> wait until later?
>
> I could find nothing to do this afternoon, except <del>to</del> read my book.
>
> After three solid days of rain he couldn't come up with anything to keep himself occupied but <del>to</del> stare out the window.
>
> In this traffic it's quicker to walk than <del>to</del> take a cab.
>
> Before the party I have to buy more wine and cheese as well as <del>to</del> pick up the dry cleaning.