# Should you duplicate prepositions when using conjunctions?

Tags: grammar, prepositions

Should you duplicate prepositions when using conjunctions?

Example sentence:

- *I swam across the river to exercise and to relax.*

Grammatically, I believe it makes equal sense as the following sentence:

- *I swam across the river to exercise and relax.*

However, is it preferable to remove the preposition after the first?

And is there a style guide rule someone can provide that mentions this scenario?

Comment: Were there two purposes, or a single combined purpose?

Comment: Hello, p-c. The _to_'s used here are not prepositions, but infinitive markers.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Enumerating with Prepositions: ''To''](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/434662/enumerating-with-prepositions-to)

Comment: More precisely, they are subordinators functioning as markers.

Comment: And they're entirely at the speaker's (or writer's) discretion. Sometimes you just want an extra syllable. Or not.

Answer (score 2):

We use multiple infinitives [to + verb] to state a series of activities.

If *exercise* and *relax* happen simultaneously with *swimming*, you better remove the second **to**.

However, if your swimming in the lake is your exercise [or maybe not] and your relaxing are different activities, then it's better to use multiple infinitives.

> "I swam across the river to exercise and to relax."

[Here](https://quillbot.com/courses/english-composition-ii/chapter/infinitives/) is a reference on how to use infinitives. Take notice of one example in the linked article:

> “Today, I plan to run three miles, to clean my room, and to update my budget.”

Comment: +1 , Check "to meet & greet" & "to have & to hold" Etc

Comment: What is this life if, full of care,
We have no time to stand and stare. [Leisure; William Henry Davies] (obviously simultaneous, so no second 'and'). // 'To be, or not **to** be.' (alternatives; can't both occur simultaneously).